# Where can you see match history for competitive CS:GO games?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Most games have match history, a breakdown of kills/deaths/assists of you and your team, the other team, and other game details.

I don't see anywhere in CS:GO where something like this is available, so is there any source that contains this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, there is a way!**

1. Click on the Watch button on main menu.

[image: Click Watch]

2. Click on the Your Matches button.

[image: Click on the Your Matches button]

3. Pick a match from the left-hand side of screen.

[image: Pick a match]

You should see the match info there. It only shows last few matches unless you download them, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Ah, that's sort of what I thought, they never implemented an actual Match History, which I find very odd. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Mh, you get the advantage of being able to watch the match from anyone's perspectives too, which is good for reporting cheaters or just generally trying to learn how to play better by watching yourself back and learning where youve gone wrong etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily watch all matches for past 6 days by opening steam app go to profile click on games After that click on personal game data .
Click on competitive matchmaking And then you can also download the replay

Answer (score -1):

I suggest one site, URL is csgostats.gg . You can have detailed stats from your matches. In CSGO under "YOUR MATCHES" tab you can only see last 8 games. On csgo stats you copy match link (as you can see on ardas screenshot, it's upper right corner) and paste it on csgostats.gg - the site will process the match and output detailed stats (like duels, k/d ratio, heat maps, weapon accuracy...).
It is really cool and useful to track your mm progress